# Having trouble adding more than 2 objects to a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on a Parallax scrolling project, in which I need to get multiple sprites up on the screen at once. To do this, and to make the code remotely reusable, I am using some vectors to hold my ParallaxSegment objects.

```
ParallaxSegment* seg;
vector<ParallaxSegment> parsega;
```

These are created as private members in my main Game class. Later on, in the Game's constructor, I have this:

```
Game::Game() : Scene("Game"),
    m_Logo(nullptr),
    seg(nullptr),
    m_Timer(0.0f)
{
    seg = new ParallaxSegment("Leaves1@2x", 1334);
    parsega.push_back(*seg);

    seg = new ParallaxSegment("Leaves2@2x", 1334);
    parsega.push_back(*seg);

    seg = new ParallaxSegment("Leaves3@2x", 1334);
    parsega.push_back(*seg);

    seg = new ParallaxSegment("Leaves4@2x", 1334);
    parsega.push_back(*seg);
}
```

The ParallaxSegments seem to be created just fine, and push_back works for the first two uses. However, upon using it a third time, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x003EED82 in GameDev2D.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000001C.
```

and am redirected to the deconstructor for Sprite, which ParallaxSegment inherits from:

```
Sprite::~Sprite()
{
    //Set the shader to null
    m_Shader = nullptr;

    //Cycle through and delete all the frames in the sprite
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_Frames.size(); i++)
    {
        delete m_Frames.at(i); //This line, specifically, is where the program terminates
        m_Frames.at(i) = nullptr;
    }

    m_Frames.clear();
}
```

I tried using just Sprites instead of my slightly modified ParallaxSegment class, but the problem still exists, and I'm brought back to the same place. Am I doing something wrong with the push_back function? Am I creating the new Sprites wrong? Should I be deleting them before making a new one?

Comment: you know that your code is leaking a lot of memory?

Comment: hint : check what will `std::vector`'s destructor do

Comment: You musn't use new in the constructor. You can put seg = (ParallaxSegment("Leaves4@2x", 1334);

Comment: Thing is that seg is a pointer, so I have to use new to assign a value.

Comment: It's not possible to tell without seeing the ParallaxSegment code. Also, when you pushback you copy your object, so the original 'new'ed one is leaked.

Comment: @Alfabit don't use a pointer... You can do directly too: parsega.push_back(ParallaxSegment("Leaves4@2x", 1334));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<ParallaxSegment> parsega;
[...]
ParallaxSegment* seg = new ParallaxSegment(...);
parsega.push_back(*seg);
```

Your vector doesn't hold pointers to ParallaxSegments but 'real' ParallaxSegment objects. Thus you create a pointer to a ParallaxSegment object, dereference it to store the object in the vector. This is 'too complicated'.

But remember: Your vector holds objects, not pointers. Thus you cannot call 'delete m_Frames.at(i)', because you try to delete an object instead of a pointer. That's when the Access Violation happens.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it! Thanks, I didn't realize that was the cause of it. I'll have to keep an eye out for that in the rest of my program.